# Badge for volonteers

Tags: printmerge

My organization would like to print badges for volunteers with name surname and birth day. Unfortunately I don't think I'm expert enough to understand how CiviCRM can do this. I would like to ask the community for suggestions. CiviCRM is installed on Wordpress.
Thanks to anyone who can help me.